# Problem with creating file on mobile device with function in game script. Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made game where all of player stats are storage in XML file. When I build a game at mobile device I get an error:

```
readonly string datapath = @"data.xml"; 
void CreateNewXMLFile(string name)
{
    XmlDocument gamedata = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode docNode = gamedata.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    gamedata.AppendChild(docNode);
    //Username
    XmlNode GameUsersNode = gamedata.CreateElement("GameUser");
    gamedata.AppendChild(GameUsersNode);
    //User
    XmlNode Username = gamedata.CreateElement("Username");
    Username.InnerText = name;
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(Username);
    //Lastlogged
    XmlNode LastloggedTime = gamedata.CreateElement("LastloggedTime");
    LastloggedTime.InnerText = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(LastloggedTime);
    //Stage
    XmlNode Stage = gamedata.CreateElement("Stage");
    Stage.InnerText = "1";
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(Stage);
    //Money
    XmlNode Money = gamedata.CreateElement("Money");
    Money.InnerText = "0";
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(Money);
    //GreenHeroLvl
    XmlNode GreenHeroLvl = gamedata.CreateElement("GreenHeroLvl");
    GreenHeroLvl.InnerText = "0";
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(GreenHeroLvl);
    //BlackHero
    XmlNode BlackHero = gamedata.CreateElement("BlackHero");
    BlackHero.InnerText = "0";
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(BlackHero);
    //AssasinHero
    XmlNode AssasinHero = gamedata.CreateElement("AssasinHero");
    AssasinHero.InnerText = "0";
    GameUsersNode.AppendChild(AssasinHero);

    gamedata.Save(datapath);
}
```

Error is:

> 06-24 21:04:47.092: E/Unity(22918): UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/data.xml" is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write to a system path `/data.xml`.

On Android you usually don't have permissions to write anything to the root `/` folder!

---

I guess you rather want to write e.g. to the [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) folder like

```
readonly string datapath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data.xml");
```

which on Android results in a valid path like

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/data.xml
```